# How to refill ammo in Insurgency?

Tags: insurgency

I like to play co-op(checkpoint) and how do I restock Ammo at a checkpoint? Is there any visual cues to where I can restock ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a *resupply*, which also lets you change your loadout. To resupply, open your loadout menu (default `m`) and click the resupply button towards the bottom right.

[image: loadout menu]

If you're in an area where you can resupply, you'll see your current supply points remaining show up in the bottom middle of your screen. This is generally located at your most recent spawn point. In co-op checkpoint mode, the most recently captured point generally becomes the resupply point (and also new spawn) (after the counterattack wave, if any).

[image: resupply point]

Some people prefer to bind the `inventory_resupply` command to a key, so they don't have to go through the loadout menu. To do so, open the developer console with the `` ` ``/`~` key and type `bind h inventory_resupply`, where `h` is the key you want to use. Then you can use just a single keypress as long as you are in a resupply point.

Comment: Aha was looking for a way to bind it after using it in game today as the menu cannot be navigated fast. Thanks.